# Html form for collecting emails don't work

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I'm trying to build email subscribtion form but it don't work for me. After click it redirects to next page but there is no data input in database. Also also it redirects after "Continue" even inputs values is blank.
Form in HTML:

```
<form action="https://www.next-page.com" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" id="name"/>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email"/>
                <label for="tac">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tac"/>
                    <span class="concheck">I have read and agree to the <a class="tac">terms and conditions</a></span>
                    <span class="please">Please, agree our terms and conditions</span>
                </label>
                <button class="continue" type="submit" name="submit"><span>+</span> Continue</button>
                <button class="carga"><img src="img/loading.gif"/></button>
                </form>
```

PHP in HTML:

```
<?php
require_once "db.php";
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO database (name, email) VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["email"]."')");
    $_POST["name"];
    $_POST["email"];
    header("Location: https://www.next-page.com");
}
?>
```

DB.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
?>
```

Comment: Show us db.php and check your error logs. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Is `$_REQUEST['submit']` populated?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this two codes into one file for example like index.php then you should remove https://www.next-page.com from action
`<form action="/" method="post">`
I think it should work.
And also there should be
`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Yes I already tryed with $_POST but it don't work either. After deleting action="" in form it don't redirect to next page.

Answer (score 0):

action should go for the PHP that will validate, so create a new PHP script that will validate it, insite put the method you want to use $_GET, or $_POST if this don't work, please use PHP + name.php on CMD/terminal and post the error here, if you trying to do this in the same page, you have to use .php on the file, and also remove the action from it.